# How would I go about extracting data that is horizoantal and formatting vertiacally in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a database that looks like this dataframe1:

```
identifier  Start      End       c1   g1    c2    g2    c3    g3
-----------------------------------------------------------------
24r       7/6/2009  7/27/2009   100    1    120    2    110   3
34e       8/6/2009  8/27/2009   200    5    180    4    190   1
34r      9/26/2009  10/17/2009  150         120   23    140   5
```

And I would like the output to be dataframe2

```
Week number week start  Week end    Identifier  cAmount
--------------------------------------------------------
    1        7/6/2009   7/13/2009      24r       100
    2       7/13/2009   7/20/2009      24r       120
    3       7/20/2009   7/27/2009      24r       110
    1        8/6/2009   8/13/2009      34e       200
    2       8/13/2009   8/20/2009      34e       180
    3       8/20/2009   8/27/2009      34e       190
    1       9/26/2009   10/3/2009      34r       150
    2       10/3/2009   10/10/2009     34r       120
    3      10/10/2009   10/17/2009     34r       140
```

I am asking this because I know this can be done using a `for`and various nested `ifs` but I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing this like with a Pandas. So the idea is in simple terms I have a horizontal dataframe that has a start date and the weeks are not separated in columns. Rather each column has vertical information. So the idea I had is to move Column 1 to 3 close to each other and then do a transpose, but this seems rather inefficient because I have more then 3 columns. If anyone knows a good method for this I would appreciate a lot.

To clarify, Dataframe 1 will be the initial data, and Column Start Will be week 1 of every identifier in dataframe 2 'week start', in dataframe 2 'week end' will be 7 days after week start. 'week start' for week number 2 would be the same as 'week end 1'. Now for  cAmount in dataframe 2. The first week value will come from dataframe 1 'c1' second week value will be from dataframe 1 'c2', and week 3 cAmount value will come from 'c3'.

A simple representation :

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the idea behind the restructuring? what columns go to week number? what columns got to cAmount? what columns go to week start and week end?

Comment: @sammywemmy I understand the question, and the answer would be this, so in the first data frame start date for identifier 24r would be week start for for identfier 24r in the second database. And camount would be c1 for camount 1. But I will edit the question and try to make things more clear.

Comment: @sammyweemy I don't know if the changes I made clarify things but I hope they do.

Comment: yea. going through it. Basically g2 is useless right?

Comment: yup g2 is completely useless

Comment: all the the columns with g are useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the date columns to datetime dtypes:

```
df.loc[:, ["Start", "End"]] = (df.loc[:, ["Start", "End"]]
                               .transform(pd.to_datetime, format="%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Let's reshape the data with pandas [wide_to_long](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj7vJujtqvuAhUs4zgGHb2yDwsQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Freference%2Fapi%2Fpandas.wide_to_long.html&usg=AOvVaw2x0C-DKYYiPjJpu1JxRkeW)

```
result = (pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                          stubnames=["c", "g"], 
                          i=["identifier", "Start", "End"], 
                          j="num")
            .reset_index()
            .drop(columns="g")
            .rename(columns={"c": "cAmount", "num": "WeekNumber"})
             )

result

    
  identifier    Start   End     WeekNumber  cAmount
0   24r     2009-07-06  2009-07-27  1   100
1   24r     2009-07-06  2009-07-27  2   120
2   24r     2009-07-06  2009-07-27  3   110
3   34e     2009-08-06  2009-08-27  1   200
4   34e     2009-08-06  2009-08-27  2   180
5   34e     2009-08-06  2009-08-27  3   190
6   34r     2009-09-26  2009-10-17  1   150
7   34r     2009-09-26  2009-10-17  2   120
8   34r     2009-09-26  2009-10-17  3   140
```

Let's generate weekly start dates using values from `Start` and `End` columns:

```
date_range = (pd.date_range(start, end, freq="7D")[:3]
              for start, end 
              in pd.unique(list(zip(result.Start, result.End))))
```

The date range is chunked since we have 3 rows per identifier. Of course, you can adjust this *manual* part; just seemed the simplest.

Let's rebuild the dataframe with appropriate inputs:

```
from itertools import chain

result.assign(
    Start=list(chain.from_iterable(date_range)),
    End=lambda df: df.Start.add(pd.Timedelta("7 days")),
)
  
   identifier   Start   End     WeekNumber  cAmount
0   24r     2009-07-06  2009-07-13  1   100
1   24r     2009-07-13  2009-07-20  2   120
2   24r     2009-07-20  2009-07-27  3   110
3   34e     2009-08-06  2009-08-13  1   200
4   34e     2009-08-13  2009-08-20  2   180
5   34e     2009-08-20  2009-08-27  3   190
6   34r     2009-09-26  2009-10-03  1   150
7   34r     2009-10-03  2009-10-10  2   120
8   34r     2009-10-10  2009-10-17  3   140
```

Comment: I am getting this error pivot_longer() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort_by_appearance'

Comment: did you install from github?

Comment: Not to worry, chunked out `pivot_longer` for `wide_to_long`

Comment: Thank you very much you are the best.

Comment: @sammyweemmy If you somehow read this could you help me with something?

Comment: @PandasINC how can I help

Comment: Well I have used your code and it works great but I have another data set in which I only have to format the dates in the way the appear before you do the data_range I have asked the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65830784/how-to-format-columns-dates-in-python-that-they-are-weekly-based-on-eachother  but the method you have provided doesn't seem to work for some reason the index is longer then the values

Comment: you are the best

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
>>> s = df[['c1', 'c2', 'c3']].stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
>>> t = df[['Start', 'End']]
          .apply(lambda x:pd.date_range(*x, freq='7D', closed='right'), axis=1)
>>> (df.reindex(s.index).assign(cAmount=s)
        .filter(regex=r'[^0-9]$', axis=1)
        .drop(['Start', 'End'], axis=1)
        .groupby(level=0)
        .apply(lambda x: x.assign(WeekNumber=x.index+1)
                          .assign(WeekStart=t[x.name].shift(-1))
                          .assign(WeekEnd=t[x.name]))
        .reset_index(drop=True)
     )

  identifier  cAmount  WeekNumber  WeekStart    WeekEnd
0        24r      100           1 2009-07-06 2009-07-13
1        24r      120           1 2009-07-13 2009-07-20
2        24r      110           1 2009-07-20 2009-07-27
3        34e      200           2 2009-08-06 2009-08-13
4        34e      180           2 2009-08-13 2009-08-20
5        34e      190           2 2009-08-20 2009-08-27
6        34r      150           3 2009-09-26 2009-10-03
7        34r      120           3 2009-10-03 2009-10-10
8        34r      140           3 2009-10-10 2009-10-17
```

**BREAKDOWN**

```
>>> s = df[['c1', 'c2', 'c3']].stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
>>> s
0    100
0    120
0    110
1    200
1    180
1    190
2    150
2    120
2    140

>>> t = df[['Start', 'End']]
          .apply(lambda x:pd.date_range(*x, freq='7D', closed='right'), axis=1)
>>> t

0    DatetimeIndex(['2009-07-13', '2009-07-20', '2009-07-27'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='7D')
1    DatetimeIndex(['2009-08-13', '2009-08-20', '2009-08-27'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='7D')
2    DatetimeIndex(['2009-10-03', '2009-10-10', '2009-10-17'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='7D')
dtype: object

>>> df.reindex(s.index).assign(cAmount=s)
  identifier      Start         End   c1   g1   c2  g2   c3   g3  cAmount
0        24r   7/6/2009   7/27/2009  100  1.0  120   2  110  3.0      100
0        24r   7/6/2009   7/27/2009  100  1.0  120   2  110  3.0      120
0        24r   7/6/2009   7/27/2009  100  1.0  120   2  110  3.0      110
1        34e   8/6/2009   8/27/2009  200  5.0  180   4  190  1.0      200
1        34e   8/6/2009   8/27/2009  200  5.0  180   4  190  1.0      180
1        34e   8/6/2009   8/27/2009  200  5.0  180   4  190  1.0      190
2        34r  9/26/2009  10/17/2009  150  NaN  120  23  140  5.0      150
2        34r  9/26/2009  10/17/2009  150  NaN  120  23  140  5.0      120
2        34r  9/26/2009  10/17/2009  150  NaN  120  23  140  5.0      140
>>> _.filter(regex=r'[^0-9]$', axis=1)

  identifier      Start         End  cAmount
0        24r   7/6/2009   7/27/2009      100
0        24r   7/6/2009   7/27/2009      120
0        24r   7/6/2009   7/27/2009      110
1        34e   8/6/2009   8/27/2009      200
1        34e   8/6/2009   8/27/2009      180
1        34e   8/6/2009   8/27/2009      190
2        34r  9/26/2009  10/17/2009      150
2        34r  9/26/2009  10/17/2009      120
2        34r  9/26/2009  10/17/2009      140
```

Then you need to drop `['Start', 'End']`, and `groupby(level=0)` i.e. by `index`. And `groupby.apply` and `pd.DataFrame.assign` other columns in the following way

```
# lets consider the first group as x:
>>> grp = (df.reindex(s.index).assign(cAmount=s)
        .filter(regex=r'[^0-9]$', axis=1)
        .drop(['Start', 'End'], axis=1)
        .groupby(level=0))
>>> x = grp.get_group(name=0)
>>> x
  identifier  cAmount
0        24r      100
0        24r      120
0        24r      110

# inside apply, x.name == 0 for the first group, 
>>> (x.assign(WeekNumber=x.index+1)
      .assign(WeekStart=t[x.name].shift(-1))
      .assign(WeekEnd=t[x.name]))
  identifier  cAmount  WeekNumber  WeekStart    WeekEnd
0        24r      100           1 2009-07-06 2009-07-13
0        24r      120           1 2009-07-13 2009-07-20
0        24r      110           1 2009-07-20 2009-07-27
>>> _.reset_index(drop=True)
  identifier  cAmount
0        24r      100
0        24r      120
0        24r      110
```